# Skip() function not working [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel-5, skip, take

I am trying to use `skip and take` function in Laravel 5... When I just use `take()` it will work find but if I add `skip()` it will not...

Here is my code:

```
public function orderWhat($what){
           $this->what = $what;
           //QUERY FOR GROUPS AND PRODJECT_GROUP
           $userCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('project_id',$this->id)->skip(20)->take(20);
                    };

           //QUERY FOR COMMENTS AND PROJECT_COMMENT     
           $commentsCondition = function($q){
                        $q->where('project_id',$this->id)->where('order',$this->what)->orderBy('comments.id', 'DESC')-skip(20)->take(20);
                    };

           //RETURN PROJECT WITH COMMENTS        
           $results = Project::with(['comments' => $commentsCondition,'groups' => $userCondition])
                                ->whereHas('groups', $userCondition)
                                ->whereHas('comments', $commentsCondition)

                                ->get();
           return $results;
       }
```

When I add `skip()` it just return blank page without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

You are missing a ">"

```
$q->where('project_id',$this->id)->where('order',$this->what)->orderBy('comments.id', 'DESC')-skip(20)->take(20);
```

Result:

```
public function orderWhat($what){
  $this->what = $what;

  $result = Project::with(['comments' => function($q) {
    $q->where('project_id',$this->id)->where('order',$this->what)
      ->skip(20)->take(20);
  }, 'groups' => function($q) {
    $q->where('user_id',Auth::id())->where('project_id',$this->id)->skip(20)->take(20);
  }])->get();

   return $results;
}
```

Comment: It will return error: `Unknown column 'order' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I got the 'order' column from your original query. Order is also a reserved keyword so it seems like you mean something else there :).

Comment: And I just need to do limit on this relation `comments`

Comment: I added them to the "with" statements now. Please try this.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mixed them up. They should be correctly now.